# Mapping Collection of Interfaces in NHibernate/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, interface, polymorphism

Say for example, I have the following:

```
public interface IPet
{
    long? Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : IPet
{
    public virtual long? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : IPet
{
    public virtual long? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the following mappings:

```
<class name="Cat" table="`Cat`" >
  <id name="Id" type="long">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name"/>
</class>

<class name="Dog" table="`Dog`" >
  <id name="Id" type="long">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name"/>
</class>
```

Now when I do the following:

```
IList<IPet> pets = session.CreateCriteria<IPet>().List<IPet>();
```

Because of implicit polymorphism, a nice feature, it returns all cats and dogs. Now consider this:

```
public class PetShop
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public List<IPet> Pets { get; set; }
}

<class name="PetShop" table="`PetShop`" >
  <id name="Id" type="long">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name"/>
  <bag name="Pets"  cascade="all">
    <key column="PetShopId"/>
    <one-to-many class="IPet"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

I was hoping this would mean the collection of pets would use implicit polymorphism to fill the collection, but instead I get the error 'Association references unmapped class: IntefaceCollectionExample.Domain.Entities.IPet'. I could create a mapping and table for IPet witch only included the Id, but this feels unintuitive. I could use union-subclass but would then lose the option to use generator class="identity". I could use many-to-any but I feel this would be rather clumsy in this case.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to create a mapping for an interface for IPet but not need a table, and then specify that Cat and Dog implement this. Or is there any better way of acheiving this than the methods I have listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit polymorphism is [not supported](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-limitations) for `one-to-many` scenarios

You can either use an explicit inheritance strategy (i.e. the whole hierarchy must be mapped, starting with the interface), or create a table for the collection and map as `many-to-any`.

Comment: When you say the whole heirachy must be mapped, are you advocating having a table for IPet like I mentioned? It does seem that what I wanted to do just can't be done. That's a shame - that would be a nice feature.

Comment: @PaulTDavies: you can avoid having a table for the interface by using the [Table per concrete class](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) strategy. But it's not necessarily better.